# Compute East-West or North-South orientation of polylines (sf linestring) in R

Tags: r, coordinates, sf, linestring

I have a shapefile of road segments, which I want to segregate as East-West and North-South when viewing on Leaflet. The repex for the sf object is as follows:

[image]

```
dfr_sf <- structure(list(ID = c(1236, 761, 931, 1336, 762), geometry = structure(list(
    structure(c(-112.142904271646, -112.142904271255, -112.142904994711, 
    -112.142905247291, -112.142905736732, 33.5414077452841, 33.5414079101852, 
    33.5417621119912, 33.5418861392355, 33.5421262682246), .Dim = c(5L, 
    2L), class = c("XY", "LINESTRING", "sfg")), structure(c(-112.203748734908, 
    -112.203752166095, -112.203773879659, 33.4343700504272, 33.4342871568118, 
    33.433762597255), .Dim = 3:2, class = c("XY", "LINESTRING", 
    "sfg")), structure(c(-112.114883625126, -112.115167266906, 
    -112.115351914246, 33.6156119199386, 33.6158868152927, 33.6161422845864
    ), .Dim = 3:2, class = c("XY", "LINESTRING", "sfg")), structure(c(-111.964783456005, 
    -111.964090535608, -111.963936568584, -111.963468137801, 
    -111.962899435723, -111.962859452241, -111.962760305322, 
    -111.962671115879, -111.962595874294, 33.6187817091371, 33.6187867477904, 
    33.6187846321183, 33.6187781929798, 33.6187886003224, 33.6187893318816, 
    33.6187911449615, 33.6187927776802, 33.6187941550603), .Dim = c(9L, 
    2L), class = c("XY", "LINESTRING", "sfg")), structure(c(-112.121866995851, 
    -112.12203194047, -112.122267474906, -112.122538463309, -112.122772543993, 
    -112.122987457062, -112.123268503597, -112.123523950945, 
    -112.123670871747, -112.123825408105, -112.123972607689, 
    33.4804339199587, 33.4804340246712, 33.480434174243, 33.480434343499, 
    33.4804344897161, 33.4804346227382, 33.4804347963288, 33.4804349515442, 
    33.4804350401811, 33.4804351351541, 33.4804352257157), .Dim = c(11L, 
    2L), class = c("XY", "LINESTRING", "sfg"))), class = c("sfc_LINESTRING", 
"sfc"), precision = 0, bbox = structure(c(xmin = -112.203773879659, 
ymin = 33.433762597255, xmax = -111.962595874294, ymax = 33.6187941550603
), class = "bbox"), crs = structure(list(input = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84", 
    wkt = "GEOGCRS[\"unknown\",\n    DATUM[\"World Geodetic System 1984\",\n        ELLIPSOID[\"WGS 84\",6378137,298.257223563,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]],\n        ID[\"EPSG\",6326]],\n    PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,\n        ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n        ID[\"EPSG\",8901]],\n    CS[ellipsoidal,2],\n        AXIS[\"longitude\",east,\n            ORDER[1],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433,\n                ID[\"EPSG\",9122]]],\n        AXIS[\"latitude\",north,\n            ORDER[2],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433,\n                ID[\"EPSG\",9122]]]]"), class = "crs"), n_empty = 0L)), row.names = c(827L, 
6013L, 387L, 1367L, 7384L), class = c("sf", "data.frame"), sf_column = "geometry", agr = structure(c(ID = NA_integer_), .Label = c("constant", 
"aggregate", "identity"), class = "factor"))
```

I want to find each ID's or line's orientation in terms of either East-West or North-South and save the computation as EW or NS under a new variable in the sf object.

**Updated based on comments**

I approached this problem by identifying the range of latitudes and longitudes for each ID. If the range of longitudes is larger, it's a East-West orientation, and vice versa. Some IDs, however, had very small difference between the range of latitudes and longitudes, so their orientation could not be identified with certainty. Lines are roads from a grid-based system, so if some lines are radial, they could be labelled as EW or NS based on the angle (relative to north) between first and last points in the ID. If angle < 45 degree, it's NS, otherwise EW.

I'm hoping there's a better approach (perhaps in terms of both angle of polyline and ranges of lat/long) to figure out the orientation. Or is there a package-based function that identifies the orientation of a polyline based on its layout/orientation on a plot/map?

Comment: What if the line segment is two points exactly NW->SE? What do you want to do with that? What about if you have line segments that jump all over the place? If you want an algorithm for some kind of summary of any data set, you should mathematically define what you mean based on why you need it. You've not done that here.

Comment: Sorry, I should've made the goal clearer. I have a shape file of road segments, which I want to segregate as East-West and North-South when viewing on leaflet. I didn't understand your first question. These line segments represent roads, most of which are in a grid. So, I doubt that the line segments would jump all over the place, at least not in the current example. But if some segments are radial, they could be labelled as EW or NS based on the angle (relative to north) between first and last points in the ID. If angle < 45 degree, it's NS, otherwise EW.

Comment: My first Q is "what's the orientation of a line from (0,0) to (1,1)? Its neither NS nor EW. Have you tried to implement working out the angle from first point to last point? Cast the line to POINT or MULTIPOINT type, get the point locations of first and last, and work out the angle using `atan2(...)`?

Comment: @Spacedman For the case you mentioned, the angle would be 45 and can be labelled as EW. But given the coordinates and mostly grid-based roads, I think it's very unlikely that such situation would arise. (I posted a simple repex for the problem I'm working on, but there's another variable like Road Name that can control the overall orientation of a corridor when multiple segments that constitute a corridor are considered.)

Comment: This is an easy task once you've defined it well enough, which you have now (angle from first to last point), except angles on  lat-long shouldn't be calculated via degree differences since 1 degree lat != 1 degree long (except on the equator). This would be much easier on a cartesian map projection - is that acceptable? You should edit your question to include your clarifications so people don't need to read all these comments.

Comment: Post updated based on comments.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some functions:

Compute the bearing using the `geosphere` package from the first to the last point of data defined as the first two columns in a matrix or data frame:

```
first_last_dir <- function(xy){
    geosphere::bearing(xy[1,1:2], xy[nrow(xy),1:2])
}
```

Get the coordinates of a spatial data frame of LINESTRING geometries, split by the `L1` attribute (which breaks features), then pass to the above function to return the bearing:

```
orient <- function(lines){
    pts = data.frame(sf::st_coordinates(lines))
    pts = split(pts, pts$L1)
    bearing = sapply(pts, first_last_dir)
    bearing    
}
```

Then you can do:

```
dfr_sf$orient = orient(dfr_sf)
```

and make some plots with the bearing as title:

```
plots <- function(d){
    for(i in 1:nrow(d)){
        plot(d$geom[i])
        title(d$orient[i])
    }
}
```

[image]

Now code up a classification of N-S or E-W based on ranges of the numbers and you're done.

Note this uses `geosphere::bearing` which works give the *initial* bearing of the shortest distance path between the points based on the ellipsoid. Note the bearing from A to B might not be the same as from B to A because you are following something like a great circle, and the bearing changes as you go. Hence its possible (on this surface) that the bearing of A to B is E-W in your classification, but the bearing from B to A is N-S in the same classification. On a small scale this is unlikely to happen but its an unavoidable consequence of geometry on an ellipsoid.